# Chirality with tautomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality, tautomer

[image]

This molecule has 6 peaks in its proton NMR. I think this is due to the following tautomerisation:

[image]

However, I am unsure as to whether this molecule would be chiral, as it can freely interconvert between these two forms, when each form is itself chiral.

Comment: The chirality is not to do with the phosphorus being a chiral centre, but rather the binaphthalene bit, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_chirality Also, the naphthalene ring has six protons, so you see six peaks. The two naphthalene rings are equivalent by symmetry ($C_2$ rotation axis).

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about axial chirality. However when the -OH group is replaced with a -Cl, there are 12 peaks seen. Does this not have C2 symmetry?

Comment: Are you referring to a phosphoryl chloride $\ce{P(=O)(Cl)(OR)2}$? If so, then no, because the P=O becomes P–Cl when you rotate 180°. Right, here it is P=O and P–OH, which shouldn't be the same, but for all intents and purposes you might as well consider them to be the same thing, exactly because of the tautomerism that you pointed out.